# Sub-Domain auto pointing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

So I am just starting on building a new application with codeigniter. What I am wanting to do is the following.

Have an auto-generated string stored in a database *-- got this part covered.*

```
// Auto Generated String    
gc149354
```

Share the auto-generated string appended to my regular domain name in an email to a client *-- got this part covered as well.*

```
// Appended to the domain name
http://gc149354.mycoolurl.com
```

All this is pretty standard coding with php and codeigniter. But where it gets tricky is actually having that url `http://gc149354.mycoolurl.com` direct the user somewhere.

I want it to direct the client to a controller in codeigniter called `newsite.php` which is stored in `controllers/new-site/newsite.php` And the controller will handle everything from there.

I am imagining I will need something in `.htaccess` on the root of my directory. Maybe like so:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule     (gc[0-9]+)/     /get-started    [NC]
```

Except that calls for `mycoolurl.com/gc149354` and not `gc149354.mycoolurl.com` right?

**So how can I route all sub-domains that start with gc follwed by 6 numbers 1-9 get routed to the getstarted controller in codeigniter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(gc[0-9]+)\.mycoolurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /controllers/new-site/newsite.php?sub=%1 [L,QSA]
```

And the "sub" GET parameter will be given the subdomain string. Or, if your controller can look at the subdomain, you can just get rid of the `?sub=%1` part.

Comment: I get `he URL "gs87984.the-green-panda.org" is not valid` which is re-directed to a page from cox, my internet provider.

Comment: Do I need to create a `wildcard sub domain` on my domain name?

Comment: @user3367639 yeah, if you don't setup the website to accept `*.mycoolurl.com`, then the server won't accept those requests.